# how to access child class variable in parent class?

Tags: android

Hi everybody,
             Am beginner to android, i have one doubt in accessing variables..  In my app, 
I have  to show the previous and next images from drawable.. it was done already.. 
But my problem was, it should play the video in parent class according to the images in child class, so  that i need to access the child class variable in parent class.... Whether it is possible or not ??   Any idea.. Thanks!

```
// Main class
public class TransitionViewExampleActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {

    ImageButton play;
    private final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC = 1000;

    private Button _leftButton;
    private Button _rightButton;
    private TransitionView _mainView;

    VideoView videoView;
    Context context;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_play_btn);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);

    _leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
    _rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
    _mainView = (TransitionView) findViewById(R.id.mainView);


    _mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}


    public void onClick(View v) {

 videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);


    switch (v.getId()) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    case R.id.ib_play_btn:



    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login to view video",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        _mainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        _leftButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        _rightButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);                    
      String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test1;
      videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
      videoView.start();

        break;


    }

    if (v == _leftButton) {

        // fadeIn.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC);

        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_right);

        _mainView.changePage(false);
    } else if (v == _rightButton) {
        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left);

        _mainView.changePage(true);

    }

   }

 }




// Sub class (Child class)


    class TransitionView extends RelativeLayout {



   /** One of the two in-memory art images */
   private ImageView _artView1;
   /** The other of the two in-memory art images */
   private ImageView _artView2;
  /** Length of art view transition animation, in milliseconds */
   private final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC = 1000;
  /** The underlying ImageSwitcher that performs transitions */
   private ImageSwitcher _imageSwitcher;
  /** Index into _imageIds array */
  private int _currentImage = 0;
  /** All available art image resource ids */

private final Integer[] _imageIds = { R.drawable.thuppaki,
        R.drawable.gouravam, R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.pic04 };

Animation fadeIn, fadeOut;

Context context;


public TransitionView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    customInit(context);
}


private void customInit(Context context) {

    _imageSwitcher = new ImageSwitcher(context);


    _imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
    _imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);

    _artView1 = new ImageView(context);
    _artView1.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);

    _artView2 = new ImageView(context);
    _artView2.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage + 1]);

    LayoutParams fullScreenLayout = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    _imageSwitcher.addView(_artView1, 0, fullScreenLayout);
    _imageSwitcher.addView(_artView2, 1, fullScreenLayout);
    _imageSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    addView(_imageSwitcher, fullScreenLayout);
}

/** @see android.view.View#View(Context, AttributeSet) */
public TransitionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    customInit(context);
}

/** @see android.view.View#View(Context, AttributeSet, int) */
public TransitionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    customInit(context);
}


public void changePage(boolean pageRight) {
    _currentImage = (pageRight) ? (_currentImage + 1) : (_currentImage - 1);
    if (_currentImage < 0) {

        _currentImage = _imageIds.length - 1;
    } else if (_currentImage >= _imageIds.length) {
        _currentImage = 0;


    }

    if (_imageSwitcher.getCurrentView() == _artView1) {

        _artView2.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);
        _imageSwitcher.showNext();
    } else {
        _artView1.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);
        _imageSwitcher.showPrevious();
    }
}   

}
```

Finally, I want to acceess the child class variables **_imageIds** and 
**_currentImage** in parent class........Any idea ???

Comment: simply you can change "private final Integer[] _imageIds" into "public final Integer[] _imageIds" and access as _mainView._imageIds

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a method in the parent class that makes the general work and then in the child classes you redefine the parent's method and you do the manipulation of `_imageIds` and `_currentImage`.

Example:

```
class Parent{

    void doSomething(){
        //your general code
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{

    @Override
    void doSomething(){
        super.doSomething(); //calls the parents function

        //add the code where you manipulate the variables
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. You can create several objects of child class and it is not clear member of which object will be accessed.

It can be done only if members are static. In this case you can access them as ClassName.memberName

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Interface` with a callback method, e.g. `onImageSelcted`.  Something like this:

```
public interface OnImageSelectedListener(){

     public onImageSelected(String imageName);

}
```

Then `implement` it in the parent class:

```
public class MyparentClass implements OnImageSelectedListner {

    @Override
    protected void onImageSelected(String imageName){
       playVideo(imageName);
    }

    childClass.setOnImageSelectedListener(this);

}


public class MyChildClass{

    private OnImageSelectedListener listener;

    public setOnImageSelectedListener(OnImageSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    // when the image is selected
    listernet.onImageSelected(imageName);
}
```